# MongoDB: Get Last Element of Array if Property Exists

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I would like to aggregate the last setting with an existing value.

My data structure:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  ...(many other fields)...
  settings: [
    {
      _id: 11,
      values: [
        {
          likesFruit: true,
          likesMeat: true,
        }
      ] 
   },
   {
      _id: 12,
      values: [
        {
          likesFruit: false
        }
      ] 
    }
  ]
}, 
{
  _id: 2,
  ...(many other fields)...
  settings: [] // empty
}
```

### Question: How to get this result

```
{
  _id: 1,
  ...(many other fields)...
  likesFruit: false,
  likesMeat: true
},
{
 _id: 2,
 ...(many other fields)...
}
```

I need a solution which doesn't remove the results where settings are e.g. empty/ not contain all props. E.g.`_id: 2` does not contain any settings. So I don't want to unwind it and filter it then for a specific setting because I still need the root object even if no setting exists.

I tried it with `addFields`:

```
$addFields: {
  likesFruit: "$settings.value.likesFruit",
  likesMeat: "$settings.value.likesMeat"
}
```

Which leaves me with this:

```
_id: 1,
...(many other fields)...
settings: [...],
likesFruit: [[true], [false]]
likesMeat: [[], [true]]
```

Which I tried to filter with:

```
$addFields: {
  likesFruit: {
    $filter: {
      input: "$likesMeat",
      as: "items",
      cond: { $ne : ["$$items", null ] }
    }
  }
}
```

My main problem is the double nesting. The "settings.value" I'm interested in has only one object inside. So I guess going from `settings.values: [{}]` to `settings.values: {}` would be a key to the solution. Then I could `project` the single values, use `$reverseArray` and `$arrayElemAt: [$array, 0]` to get the last element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of [$mergeObjects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/) operator since as the documentation states:

> mergeObjects overwrites the field values as it merges the documents. If documents to merge include the same field name, the field, in the resulting document, has the value from the last document merged for the field.

As you have nested arrays you need double [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) to aggregate your data. You can also use [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) to promote your aggregated values to the top level

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            settingsAggregated: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$settings",
                    initialValue: {},
                    in: {
                        $mergeObjects: [ "$$value", 
                            { $reduce: { input: "$$this.values", initialValue: {}, in: { $mergeObjects: [ "$$value", "$$this" ] } } }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $mergeObjects: [ "$$ROOT", "$settingsAggregated" ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            settings: 0,
            settingsAggregated: 0
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ejNlo1P75kD)